# How do I create an SSRS hyperlink to take you to a specific page of the report?

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink

I would like to provide a hyperlink to end users to take them to a specific page of the report instead of the first one - i.e. to take them directly to page 3 of the SSRS report. Is there a way to add something to the link I provide to them to do this?

I think adding something like page=3 to the end of the link but I can't figure out exactly how.

Comment: I've never tried this but *if* you can do this you would probably need to setup bookmarks and reference those so trying using bookmark/url etc in your search. You can set links to bookmarks within a report but I'm not sure if you can reference them from a URL. Good luck

Comment: You can make bookmarks pointing on report items like tablixes, subreports or inside them like groups etc. In that case the report will contain a bookmark table which by clicking will redirect the user to the related part of the report.